# Bind ngx-bootstrap datepicker to ngModel so that isDirty can be evaluated

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

All that I really want is to know when the date value has been changed so that I can enable/disable the submit button.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="AdvertisingCost_PaymentDate">{{l("PaymentDate")}}</label>
  <input 
     required 
     class="form-control m-input"                                      
     #AdvertisingCost_PaymentDate
     type="datetime" 
     bsDatepicker                                       
     datePickerLuxonModifier     
     [(date)]="advertisingCost.paymentDate"                                                                   
     name="AdvertisingCost_PaymentDate"                                     
  >
  <validation-messages [formCtrl]="AdvertisingCost_PaymentDate"></validation-messages>
</div>
```

If I change [(date)] to [(ngModel)] it responds to the change event and sets isDirty to true; however, when the form is initially displayed, the current value says 'Invalid Date'.

If I leave [(date)], the date is initially displayed correctly; however, changing the date with the picker does not set the isDirty flag.

I've tried formatting the data using bsValue to various formats, but the result is always 'Invalid Date' even though there is a valid date being returned from the API:

```
paymentDate!: DateTime;
this.paymentDate = _data["paymentDate"] ? DateTime.fromISO(_data["paymentDate"].toString()) : <any>undefined;
```

How do I get this to work?  I have lots of forms with lots of dates on each form and I'm hoping to just use isDirty to evaluate change events and avoid a bunch of code to check for changed data.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the date field isolated from form group.
Define paymentDate variable and on change trigger the formControl.
If change doesnt work try to patch the form Control.

```
[(ngModel)]="paymentDate" (change)="advertisingCost.paymentDate=paymentDate"
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Comment: Thank you...I'm new to Angular and I'm grateful for your assistance.